# getting number from php file with jquery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm new to AJAX and jQuery.  I'm trying to pass a number from unrate.php to be used as checkVal (as shown below).  The file does a bunch of stuff but it only echos the number.  When I add a alert(checkVal) it shows a invalid character and than the number I want. (I just want the number)...

### ajax handler:

```
$.get("unrate.php?numb="+ID, function(checkVal){
  if (checkVal == 1) {
    number.innerHTML = addNumb + 1;
  } else { 
    number.innerHTML = addNumb - 1;
  }
});
```

### unrate.php:

```php
<?php
$uNum = $_SESSION['userNum'];
$ider = $_GET['numb'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratecheck WHERE ID =".$ider);
$checkRay = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$checkVal = $checkRay[$uNum];

$sqlZ = mysql_query("UPDATE ratecheck SET `".$uNum."`=0 WHERE ID=".$ider)
or die(mysql_error());

    $sqlB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sources WHERE ID =".$ider);
    $sourceRay = mysql_fetch_array($sqlB);
    $newRC = $sourceRay['ratecount'] - 1;

    mysql_query("UPDATE sources SET ratecount =".$newRC." WHERE ID =".$ider)
    or die(mysql_error());

if ($checkVal > 1)
    {   
    $newpts = $sourceRay['points'] - 1; 
    $userEmail = $sourceRay['user'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE sources SET points =".$newpts." WHERE ID =".$ider)
    or die(mysql_error());  

        if ($_SESSION['userName']) 
        {
            $findUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '".$userEmail."'") or mysql_error();
            $currentRate = mysql_fetch_array($findUser);
            $newrating = $currentRate['rating'] - 1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rating =".$newrating." WHERE email LIKE '".$userEmail."'")
            or mysql_error();      

        }
        else
        {
            die('ERROR');
        }
    }
else 
    {
    $newpts = $sourceRay['points'] + 1; 
    $userEmail = $sourceRay['user'];


    mysql_query("UPDATE sources SET points =".$newpts." WHERE ID =".$ider)
    or die(mysql_error());

        if ($_SESSION['userName']) 
        {
            $findUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '".$userEmail."'") or mysql_error();
            $currentRate = mysql_fetch_array($findUser);
            $newrating = $currentRate['rating'] + 1;
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rating =".$newrating." WHERE email LIKE '".$userEmail."'")
            or mysql_error();      

        }
        else
        {
            die('ERROR');
        }
    }
echo $checkVal;
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: can you post `unrate.php` code ??

Comment: you can use console.log( checkVal) to see exactly what you are getting from the server. the code seems fine, if all you get from the server is echo.

Comment: Please post your PHP code which does the output and Javascript code with alert();

Comment: http://imgur.com/EUZzR this what it says when I add a alert(checkVal) right inside the function.  The code in unrate.php is kinda long but here lol: http://libertariantee.com/uploads/asdf.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra characters at the beginning or end of your output are something you occasionally run into with php. I greatly endorse the comment that suggests looking at the raw output from the server. You might also want to think about these possibilities:

Invisible characters at the beginning or end of your script file. Use a text editor that will show you hidden characters (even a hex editor) and see if there are any. Also, you don't have to end your php script with `?>` if you're not doing anything else past it. You can just leave it open, as that will prevent characters showing up at the end.

Check the character encoding that your script has. This might not be the solution, but some time ago I had a similar situation that went away when I changed the encoding to UTF8 without Byte-Order Mark. Try doing the same thing and see if that fixes it

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I was messing around tryin' your advice and I saved the PHP file as ANSI and it seems to be working now. You're the man!  Thanks so much.

Comment: @user1710875 If this answer solved your problem then you should mark it as accepted answer. See [FAQ section about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).